# wget Pulling Data from Different Webpage

Tags: php, cookies, web-scraping, wget

I'm currently using wget to pull data from a password protected website. Unfortunately, the data being saved is not from the correct webpage. For example, when I enter:

`wget -O filename.txt --cookies=on --load-cookies=./cookies.txt http://www.draftexpress.com/blue/player.php?player=1086&year=2015&split=totals`

it saves the webpage data from http://www.draftexpress.com/blue/player.php?player=1086. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I am pretty new to wget, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the username and password to the site to get authenticated. The response you are currently getting is basically the website saying your access was denied. You can add `wget --user= --password=`  to your list of arguments.

Comment: So would that look like `wget --user=username --password=password -O filename.txt --cookies=on --load-cookies=./cookies.txt http://www.draftexpress.com/blue/player.php?player=1086&year=2015&split=totals`? I tried that and had the same result

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting? You can also try the --ask-password option. So leave out --password  and replace it with --ask-password and it should prompt you for a password. You'll need to still use the --user option though. Hope this helps.

Comment: The `--ask-password` method isn't working either. I'm not getting any errors as I'm able to get past the login page of the website, but as I mentioned, the page source data that is saved into the `filename.txt` file is that of http://www.draftexpress.com/blue/player.php?player=1086 and not http://www.draftexpress.com/blue/player.php?player=1086&year=2015&split=totals